# Integrating $x^c (1-x)^d$ from 0 to 1 using the gamma function

Tags: integration, gamma-function

I am trying to solve the following integral:
$$
\int_0^1 x^c (1-x)^d dx 
$$
for some $c, d \in \mathbb{R}$
I know I have to use the gamma function, I have tried using the substitutions $u = ln\frac{1}{x}$ as well as  $u = ln\frac{1}{1-x}$ to try to make this appear as a gamma function but neither have gotten me closer to an answer.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beta_function

Comment: Try $x=\sin^2(t)$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint:

$$\int_0^1 t^{x-1}(1-t)^{y-1}dt=B(x,y)=\frac{\Gamma(x)\Gamma(y)}{\Gamma(x+y)}$$

Comment: But is there a way to do it using only the gamma function and its definition?

Comment: @AbdelrahmanSameh A proof of the Beta Function comes from using the definition of the gamma function. I believe it's on Wikipedia